# WP js_composer.min.css not applying for single post

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, visual-composer

I have an issue with my footer in single-post pages. My footer should look like

---

[image: this]

But when I open single post page it turns out to look like

---

[image: this].

When I inspected both footers I found out that any other page the css rules apply from  `js_composer.min.css` but on single-post page you do not see it there.

Is there any way to add that to single-post?

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem but with Woocommerce pages.

This should work for you.

```
function js_composer_front_load() {
    if(is_single()) {
        wp_enqueue_style('js_composer_front');
    }
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'js_composer_front_load');
```